# Is it possible to create a background image slider using only html/css

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a slider on my website, and so far I have only been able to achieve it using an actual `<img>` instead of a background image, I know it is possible to get your images to fade in and then fade out but I'm wondering if is possible to make your background images slide off the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tyampus.net](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/) has a good working explanation that involved using HTML and CSS3. Here it is explained below:

According to the link:

**Step 1**
For this part, you have to create a ul element, which serves as the base framework for the slider: Here is the snipped used to describe the following:

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li>
        <span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><!--Other imgs--></li>
    <li><!--...--></li>
</ul>
```

*(The spans will have the background images)*

**Step 2**

Next, basic styling have to be added to the list, they include making sure the element is fixed and stretches over the viewport.

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(img.png) repeat top left; 
}
```

**Step 3**
*(the image will be positioned absolutely with a height and width of 100%. The code is as follows.)*

```
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
```

The next snipped will set the animation 36 seconds long:

```
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
```

**Step 4** This defines the pictures for the slider and the animation delay:

```
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
```

*(The image animation selector)*

```
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

This animation happens at such amounts for the fade out

**Step 5**

For non animation supporting browsers, add the following rule

```
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, rather than just providing a link.

Comment: The Tyampus link gives enough explanation.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, you need to add the important details from the link, in case the link is broken in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the multiple background support of CSS3 and use standard animations for the sliding:

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports?_=1) 0 0 no-repeat,
    url(http://loremflickr.com/600/400/sports?_=2) 600px 0 no-repeat,
    url(http://loremflickr.com/600/400/sports?_=3) 1200px 0 no-repeat,
    url(http://loremflickr.com/600/400/sports?_=4) 1800px 0 no-repeat;
  animation: slide-right 15s forwards 1s;
}
@keyframes slide-right{
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 600px 0, 1200px 0, 1800px 0
  }
  16%, 33% {
    background-position: -600px 0, 0 0, 600px 0, 1200px 0
  }
  49%, 66% {
    background-position: -1200px 0, -600px 0, 0 0, 600px 0
  }
  85%, 100% {
    background-position: -1800px 0, -1200px 0, -600px 0, 0 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow"></div>
```