# CSS Slide Animation on Fullscreen Images

Tags: html, css, background, css-animations

I have two images on my landing page which go back and forth with the default fade animation. My first problem is **I want to use a sliding animation** but I didn't find any option to change it. My second problem is **the fade animation only works for chrome**. Is there any way to solve this in other browsers?

**My code:**

```css
/* basicStyle.css */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: skyblue;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

/* Section Images */
section#home {
  background: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section#gallery {
  background: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section#about {
  background: green;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section#contact {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* LandingPage.css */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597368208802-2bec16fba411?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80')
  100vw 0 no-repeat,
url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597390520089-9f46046ea040?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1041&q=80')
  0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  animation: slide-right 15s forwards 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    background-position: 100vw 0, 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 0vw 0, 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100vw 0, 0 0;
  }
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#showcase .button {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: #fff 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-section div.iScrollIndicator {
  background: white !important;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgba(57, 77, 95, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttons .button {
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> -->
  <header id="showcase">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#about" class="button"><span>About</span></a>
      <a href="#gallery" class="button"><span>Gallery</span></a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="gallery">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to replace the fade animation with a slide animation? Or the other parts of the page?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the fade animation with a slide animation

Comment: I want to earn a really similar result like this. Only difference is my images are fullscreen images and there are some text above them... [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j18CH0Grhbw)

Comment: other browsers should work unless you meant IE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235326/8782778) and created the following snippet:

It uses multiple backgrounds, puts the top-layer one a screen-size to the right and then moves it in.

Very simple and you can add more images easily. The code comments show you how :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: skyblue;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

/* Section Images */
section#home {
  background: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section#gallery {
  background: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section#about {
  background: green;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section#contact {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* LandingPage.css */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  /*/ Last image first, add 100vw for each additional image. For infinite, make first picture the last /*/
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597390520089-9f46046ea040?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1041&q=80")
      300vw 0 no-repeat,
    url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521020781921-ce0d582b7665?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80")
      200vw 0 no-repeat,
    url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597368208802-2bec16fba411?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80")
      100vw 0 no-repeat,
    url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597390520089-9f46046ea040?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1041&q=80")
      0 0 no-repeat;
  /*/ For every image, one cover /*/
  background-size: cover, cover, cover, cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  animation: slide-right 8s forwards 1s infinite;
}
/*/ For four pictures, make keyframes at 0%, 25%, 75%, 100%, for 6 pictures make 0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% etc./*/
@keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    /*/ Add one 100vw 0 for each picture at every stage. It's always like a reverse stairway downwards /*/
    /* 3 100vw's*/
    background-position: 100vw 0, 100vw 0, 100vw 0, 0 0;
  }
  33% {
    /*2 100vw's*/
    background-position: 100vw 0, 100vw 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  }
  66% {
    /* 1 100vw'*/
    background-position: 100vw 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    /* The end - none left :)*/
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  }
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#showcase .button {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: #fff 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-section div.iScrollIndicator {
  background: white !important;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgba(57, 77, 95, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttons .button {
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav> -->
  <header id="showcase">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>

    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#about" class="button"><span>About</span></a>
      <a href="#gallery" class="button"><span>Gallery</span></a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="gallery">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got ahead with this solution and I also managed to set this go infinitely. I edited my code snippet! My question is: how can I add more than 2 pictures and make them go infinitely?

Comment: I will edit the snipped and write a section about that in my answer

Comment: Added some code comments, that show you how to do it :)

Comment: Really nice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try to rearrange `background-position` in the `animation` section which has numbers are in unit of Viewport Width(`vw`) in manner way.

If there are 3 images in the `background` arrangement will be like the following

> 1. `100vw 0, 100vw 0, 0 0`
> 2. `100vw 0, 0 0, 0 0`
> 3. `0 0, 0 0, 0 0`

and also you can simply add [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) property in your code on `<html>` tag in order to make [`smooth`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) scroll which also makes page look nicer when scroll event takes place.

### example

```css
html{scroll-behavior: smooth;}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
}
section,
#showcase {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
section#gallery,
section#home,
section#about,
section#contact,
#showcase{min-height: 100vh;}
section{width: 100%;}
section h1 {font-size: 4rem;}
section#home {background: black;}
section#gallery {background: red;}
section#about {background: green;}
section#contact {background: blue;}
#showcase {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597390520089-9f46046ea040?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1041&q=80")
    200vw 0 no-repeat, 
    url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597368208802-2bec16fba411?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80")
    100vw 0 no-repeat,
    url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597390520089-9f46046ea040?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1041&q=80")
    0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: slide-right 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes slide-right {
0% {background-position: 100vw 0, 100vw 0, 0 0;}
60% {background-position: 100vw 0, 0 0, 0 0;}
100% {background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;}
}

#showcase h1 {font-size: 50px;}
#showcase .button {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.buttons .button {margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <header id="showcase">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#about" class="button"><span>About</span></a>
      <a href="#gallery" class="button"><span>Gallery</span></a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="gallery">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
  </section>
</div>
</html>
```

I also edit too much to avoid unnecessary things which were in the code and DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) as well but I hope you will find it helpful.